# Action Script 3.0 HitTestObject Not Working?

Tags: actionscript-3

Help me..   i'm making rpg for my school project and the code hitTestObject inside NPC01 class is not working.

Here's my code:

Game.as

```
package {
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.Event;

    public class Game extends MovieClip{
       var map:Map = new Map();
       var player:Player = new Player();
       var npc:NPC = new NPC();

       public function Game(){
         addChild(map);
         addChild(npc);
         addChild(player);
         this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,loop);
       }
       private function loop():void {
         npc.x = map.x;
         npc.y = map.y;
       }
     }
   }
```

NPC.as

```
    package  {
      import flash.display.MovieClip;
      import flash.events.Event;

      public class NPC extends MovieClip {

        var npc01:NPC01 = new NPC01();

        public function NPC() {
            // constructor code

            addChild(npc01);            

            npc01.x = 20;
            npc01.y = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

NPC01.as

```
package  {
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.Event;

    public class NPC01 extends MovieClip {      

        var player:Player = new  Player();

        public function NPC01() {
            // constructor code
            this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, loop);
        }
        private function loop(e:Event):void
        {
            if(player.hitTestObject(npc)) {  //npc is a movieclip  inside NPC01
              trace("HIT!!");   
              }
        }
```

i got no error message. it just, whenever the player movieclip hits npc movieclip, the output doesn't show up..

i tried also to also to trackdown their position using:

```
trace( player.getBounds(stage) );
trace( npc.getBounds(stage) );
```

result:

```
(x=343, y=218, w=26, h=45)
(x=334, y=218, w=32, h=51)
```

it seems that they are colliding.

But when i write the hitTestObject code inside the Game.as under function loop, and the trace output show's up when the player hits npc.

i got no problem moving the charater 'player' around.

Sorry for my bad English.

i also tried these inside NPC01.as under loop function:

```
if (npc.hitTestObject(player)) {
  trace("Hit01");
}
if (npc.hitTestObject(player)) {
    trace("Hit02");
}
if (npc.hitTestPoint(player.x, player.y, true)) {
    trace("Hit03");
}
if (player.hitTestPoint(npc.x, npc.y, true)) {
    trace("Hit04");
}
```

but only "Hit03" is responding..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're creating **two different** Player objects, when you only need **one**.

This should work better for your purposes:

```
package {
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.Event;

public class Game extends MovieClip{
   var map:Map = new Map();
   var player:Player = new Player();
   var npc:NPC = new NPC(player);

   public function Game(){
     addChild(map);
     addChild(npc);
     addChild(player);
     this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,loop);
   }
   private function loop():void {
     npc.x = map.x;
     npc.y = map.y;
   }
 }
```

}

```
package  {
  import flash.display.MovieClip;
  import flash.events.Event;

  public class NPC extends MovieClip {

    var player:Player;
    var npc01:NPC01;

    public function NPC(player:Player) {
        // constructor code
        this.player = player;
        npc01 = new NPC01(player);
        addChild(npc01);            

        npc01.x = 20;
        npc01.y = 0;
    }
}
```

}

```
package  {
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.Event;

public class NPC01 extends MovieClip {      

    var player:Player;

    public function NPC01(player:Player) {
        // constructor code
        this.player = player;
        this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, loop);
    }
    private function loop(e:Event):void
    {
        if(player.hitTestObject(npc)) {  //npc is a movieclip  inside NPC01
          trace("HIT!!");   
          }
    }
```

Comment: hi sir. but what about if i need to check the collision of the other layer. let's say, i add one child in the Game.as and i'm going to hittestobject that child from the Npc01.as too?

Comment: Well, this is the main problem of your design, as HankScorpio already pointed out. Checking for hitTestObject "should" be done outside of both your Player and your NPC classes. Otherwise you'll need to daisy-chain references to all possible players to all possible NPCs or vice versa.

Comment: ahm, thank you again. i guess i need to change my code, any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Here are the DisplayObjects you have:

- (game):Game
- - map:Map
- - player:Player
- - npc:NPC
- - - npc01:NPC01
- - - - player:Player
- - - - npc:MovieClip

Notice that you've created two Players (one in Game, and one in NPC01). Are you sure you're testing against the correct one?

I'm guessing you probably want just one. Try this.

```
package {
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.Event;

public class Game extends MovieClip{
    var map:Map = new Map();
    var player:Player = new Player();
    var npc:NPC = new NPC();

public function Game(){
    addChild(map);
    addChild(npc);
    addChild(player);
    this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,loop);
}
private function loop():void {
    npc.x = map.x;
    npc.y = map.y;

    if(player.hitTestObject(npc)) {
        trace("HIT!!");   
    }
}
```

}

And remove Player from NPC01:

```
package {
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.Event;

public class NPC01 extends MovieClip {    
    public function NPC01() {
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for reply..  i had already try that and it works, but i need to the hittestobject function inside the NPC01 because i will use it for dectecting collision on player and objects when the npc's moving around..  yes, i created player inside npc to check hitTestObject and no error showing.

Comment: NPC doesn't need to have any reference to Player at all.
It feels intuitive that each NPC/Player etc should be autonomous and be able to see and hittest etc on their own (because that's what humans do), but that approach is more difficult to maintain as your code grows.

Make a class that will manage each Player and NPC. You probably want to store a reference to each of them in an array (or Vector, for better performance) inside that new class.
Then, at each ENTER_FRAME event, call a method on the manager that loops through all your NPC and hittest them against the Player.